# WIN32 change the text insideTextOut

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui

This will diplay the text on the screen with a TRANSPARENT BG and A colored text, but what if i want to change the

text later, how do i do? should i use: SendMessage();  or: SetWindowText( ) If yes, how and if

no, then what then??? and how

```
case WM_PAINT:

       dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &Ps);

SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT);

        SetTextColor(dc, RGB(454,0,0)); 

       TextOut(dc, 10, 200, L"SEE? ", 5);

       EndPaint(hwnd, &Ps);

       break;
```

Comment: Use a *variable* so this code can paint any text.  Call InvalidateRect() when you change the variable so the window paints the new text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw the text associated with your window - this is what you should do:

1. Don't call `TextOut` with the hard-coded string. Instead obtain it via `GetWindowText`.
2. Add a hander to `WM_SETTEXT` message. Upon receiving it - invalidate your window (or at least the area where the text is assumed to be drawn).

Now some explanations about transparency and etc.

I assume your window has an associated background brush (i.e. its `WNDCLASS` had non-zero `hbrBackground` member upon class registration). If not - you're painting a transparent text above a non-painted area, which may contain any junk.

During the call to `BeginPaint` your window procedure receives `WM_ERASEBACKGROUND`. Assuming you pass it to the `DefWindowProc` - the client area of your window will be filled by the background brush. So that every time you begin painting - the client are of your window will be filled by some brush. Then you draw your text transparently on the newly-filled background. So that no smearing should occur.

Whenever you want to change something visual on your window - drawing extra things in-place is not enough. Because at any time your window may be requested by the OS to redraw itself. So that your window must be able to paint itself adequately upon receiving `WM_PAINT`.

A common practice is to invalidate your window (or a part of it, using `InvalidateRect` or similar function) upon some change. And then, when you receive `WM_PAINT` - repaint your window.